# append script and links work in practice but not in application

Tags: javascript

I am using js to get the HTML for my websites navbar. instead of having to paste it on each page,
that part works great. the issue is afterwards i create a script and link element, to provide the javascript and the css file that goes with the navbar. using brackets application it works. but in real world application i'm getting error 404, i've checked the location and it seams to be correct.

also. is there a way to tell when the html from the fetch method is completed? i have a set timeout() function of 6ms as without it it's a 50-50 shot of loading the js file before the html. like a window.onload() command.

```
//Getting include attribute value
function getHTML() {
var includes = document.getElementsByTagName('include');
for(let i=0; i<includes.length; i++){
   let include = includes[i];
   
   //Loading include src value 
   load_file(includes[i].attributes.src.value, function(text){
        include.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', text);
        include.remove();
   });
}

        const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        script = document.createElement("script"),
          head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        link = document.createElement('Link');
        link.setAttribute('rel',"styleSheet")
    link.setAttribute('href','/wont-work');
    head.appendChild(link)
    setTimeout(()=> {
    script.setAttribute("src","/Navbar.js");
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javaScript")
    body.appendChild(script);
    },6);
    
}
function load_file(filename, callback) {
   fetch(filename).then(response => response.text()).then(text => callback(text));
    console.log('file loaded')
}

window.addEventListener("load", getHTML);
```

expecting the CSS and Javascript to NOT be 404

Comment: Does `Navbar.js` start with an uppercase 'N' in its directory listing? I ask because filenames are case senstive under Linux but not under Windows. It would also greatly assist readers if you could add the server directory structure to the post with enough information for [readers to reproduce and debug the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).